# Ionic menu based on condition

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i want right inside side (right or left) depend on value of rtl in controller

rtl value (true or false) in controller

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="rtl ? 'right' : 'left'">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: What if you try to wrap the expression in double curly brackets ?
`{{rtl ? 'right' : 'left'}}`

Comment: if(rtl == true){ side="right"} else {side="left"}

Comment: you mean toggle left or toggle right?

Comment: yes that what i mean depend on value on controller